# How do i get the previous state value of the checkbox in class based component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a scenario where I need to check the previous state of the checkbox with the new value of the checkbox
say at first-time checkbox is checked and I will save it
on edit i will uncheck this but the save button is not getting enabled because the state is getting updated to uncheck(false) value
i need to compare the old value with new value

```
state = {
status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
return {
  ...prevState,
  status: !prevState.status
}
})
}
```

Comment: If you need to store two state values (current state and original state) then you need to store *two* values in your `state` object.  *"but the save button is not getting enabled because the state is getting updated to uncheck"* - That doesn't necessarily sound like you need to compare current with previous, that sounds like you need better UX logic.  By what logic is the save button enabled/disabled?  If you want to enable it when changes are made anywhere in the form, then as soon as *anything* updates state you can set a state value like `isDirty` and enable the button based on that.

Comment: @David isDirty to set a flag??can i get small example for that

Comment: `isDirty` is just an example of what to name a variable which indicates whether a form has changed (whether it's "dirty") or not.  You can name it anything you like, such as `formHasChanged` or `hasNewData`.  It's just a state value like any other.  The idea is that, instead of comparing all of the form values and making complex logic to try to *infer* if data has been modified, just store a boolean value which *indicates* that data has been modified.  Default it to false, and as soon as anything on the form changes update it to `true`.